# Approach to automatically determining the source of data matrix singularity?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, singular-matrix

When you're using R built-in glm functions (and in other languages I assume), the software has a built-in ability to automatically eliminate redundant or inestimable parameters. For example, when there is exact collinearity, or if there are empty cells in a contingency table defined by a categorical interaction. For example:

```
x1 = rnorm(100)
x2 = 2*x1
y = x1 + rnorm(100)
summary( glm(y ~ x1 + x2) ) 

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.1031     0.1007  -1.024    0.308    
x1            0.9991     0.1041   9.594 9.21e-16 ***
x2                NA         NA      NA       NA
```

I am attempting to write a simple program for similar types of model fitting (basically a modification of a parametric GLM to accommodate interval-censored outcomes) and would like to easily identify and eliminate such singularities in a similar fashion to what `glm()` is doing but I'm having trouble figuring this one out.

The reason I know singularities come is because when I try to invert the estimated covariance matrix of the estimates (based on an estimate of the fisher information) it is numerically singular.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code, particularly as related to this message string?

Comment: I have looked at `glm()` source code a bit, but it calls so many sub-functions, it's hard to figure out where to look. The question is more about, analytically, what is an effective way to characterize problems like this, so I can then write exception handling code based on that.

Comment: The `R` approach is buried in a DLL function to compute the QR decomposition of the model matrix: the linear dependencies can be read directly off the $R$ (upper triangular) matrix.